# python round numbers to specific value

Tags: python, numpy, math, rounding, ceil

I would like to write a specif rounding logic.

```
number = x

if x < 950:
    # round number to and in steps of 50
elif x < 9000:
    # round number to and in steps of 100
elif x < 100000:
    # round number to and in steps of 250
else:
    # round number to and in steps of 1000
```

This is my idea how it could work.

What I need for example, if x = 123 then the it should be rounded to 100.
if x = 170 it should be rounded to 200, and then for example for x = 8568 it should round to 8600

Comment: Something like `round(8568/100)*100` or `round(170/50)*50` ?

Comment: Is `x` always an integer? Which direction should halfway-cases round (e.g., `825` or `1350`)?

Comment: Why would `170` round to `200` rather than `150`? `150` is closer,  so it's not clear to me what rule you're using here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostlikely not the cleanest way to do it but :
`(x + step/2)//step*step` should work.

Example :
`print((880+25)//50*50)` returns `900`.